# Loss of GPS Signal simulation in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, adt

I need to simulate loss and reacquisition of GPS signal in Android Emulator, but I haven't found any commands like `geo no-fix` or so. How does one simulate moving through a tunnel or so with the emulator?

To be more precise, I need `status` in `LocationListener.onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)` to change from `LocationManager.AVAILABLE` to `LocationManager.TEMPORARY_UNAVAILABLE` and back.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the status bar (or whatever it's called, where the time, battery, etc. is shown) you can disable GPS (at least on Android 5). That is just enough to simulate that, taking that the app will only be paused while you move the action bar down.